# Update MySQL column based on multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

How can I modify this statement to set the region value where there are multiple values in the location_town column?

```
UPDATE `wp_em_locations` SET `location_region` = 'The-Valley'
WHERE `location_town` = 'Bond'
```

IE: Bond is not the only town, I have many town names but all should be used to set `location_region = The-Valley`.

How do I accomplish this using one statement? Or do i need to run the same statement for each town name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either an `OR` or `IN` statement

```
WHERE `location_town` IN ('Bond', 'OtherTown')
```

or (no pun intended)

```
WHERE `location_town` = 'Bond' OR `location_town` = 'OtherTown'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the statement more complex than this? if you're trying to set every row to have `location_region` set to 'The-Valley' why use the where clause, which only serves to limit the scope of the update query?

Would this do what you're looking for, are am I misunderstanding?

```
UPDATE `wp_em_locations` SET `location_region` = 'The-Valley' WHERE 1;
```